# How do I consume a ColdFusion webservice from C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, coldfusion

I'm trying to use a webservice with the endpoint `https://services.example.com/ASP_SecureWebServices.cfc?wsdl`.

In the documentation I have this:

#### Request

```
<authorise>
  <site>xxx</site>
  <login>xxx</login>
  <password>xxx</password>
  <partnerid>xxx</partnerid>
  <wstype>xpt_exhibitors</wstype>
</authorise>
```

#### Authenticated Response

```
<authorisation>
  <service>getAuthToken</service>
  <authorised>OK</authorised>
  <authtoken>255461</authtoken>
</authorisation>
```

I’ve never used ColdFusion before, so I don’t understand how to make the request. Can anyone assist?

I’ve added a service reference like this:

[image: Screenshot]

But I don’t get this method:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you add it as a web reference or a service reference? Also, can you show the code that you're using to call the service?

Comment: Its a service reference. and there is no code, I'm trying to use the easy "plug and play" thing from Visual Studio, it works for me for all WCF webservices. but didn't work here

Comment: Well, after you add the reference, visual studio caches the DTO's and methods to call the service. So, you still need to use code to invoke the service (unless you're using wwf). In the second screenshot above, can copy the whole code you've typed instead giving a partial screenshot?

Comment: There is no code to show at all, what I did is this: 1)add a service reference --- 2)create a client ----- 3)trying to call the operation, but its not there.

Comment: Pay attention to what you show in the two screenshots. The first indicates ASP_Secure... where as the other ASP_Export... these are different services. I wonder if you're using the same service name for both services and things are getting mangled up.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but both of them dont show any operations. I just need to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if I should to call the web service company to fix it.

Comment: http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2007/08/13/add-service-reference-in-vs-2008/

Comment: A public WSDL service URL example. http://dgpys.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis?wsdl  Try with this to check if the problem is the Coldfusion webservice or something on your side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're actually hitting the CFC directly, but you add ?wsdl on the end to actually have it return the WSDL.

Also, all of your methods in that CFC that you want accessible will need `access="remote"`.

So your actual endpoint would be closer to this:

```
https://services.example.com/ASP_SecureWebServices.cfc?wsdl
```

Comment: I think the endpoint is right, because when I add this as a service reference in Visual Studio, I get a list of methods. But I can't access these methods from code (after creating the client)

Comment: What you originally listed is the resulting URL that leads to the Javadocs for the CFC.  It will give you a sort of friendly HTML representation of the methods on the object, any hints added to the component, methods, or arguments, datatypes, etc.  But it's not the same thing as the WSDL used for webservices.

If I'm developing locally, I'll just hit the user's CFC directly in my web browser.  So something like http://localhost/mysite/ASP_SecureWebServices.cfc, this will redirect me to a url like you describe above, asking for the CF password.  But add ?wsdl on the end of that url, boom, wsdl.

Comment: I see. But how I can use it after getting the endpoint? Can I use it just like any WCF webservice? I mean like adding the service reference and call the methods?

Comment: You should be able to use it like any other webservice, yes.  ColdFusion webservices are designed to be kind of "plug and play" for developers.  Where you might run into issues is with datatypes.  The array of datatypes available to you in .NET probably won't be represented in the ColdFusion webservice.  Moreover, whatever they convert to on your end might be some older, deprecated datatypes, depending on the webservice.

I should add:  Most senior CF devs, in my experience, hate the built-in SOAP functionality, since it abstracts so much of the wiring under the hood from our control.

Comment: That didn't work for me, I added the service reference, and created the client, I don't have any of the listed operations. the only one that might make sense is OpenAsync method, but it doesn't take any parameter. how can I call these methods?

Comment: (Edit) @user836252 - Silly question, but did you try calling the methods anyway? I noticed something similar in a test with VS2005,  but was still able to invoke the web service methods, even though they were not listed where I expected them to be. ie MyCFWebserviceTest test = new MyCFWebserviceTest(); String result = test.someFunction("john", "password");

Answer (score 7):

Going to go out on a limb, but my guess from the documentation is that the method you need to access is called `authorise`. With that in mind, you would call the web service as follows:

```
https://services.example.com/ASP_SecureWebServices.cfc?method=authorise&site=xxx&login=xxx&password=xxx&partnerid=xxx&wstype=xpt_exhibitors
```

By default, ColdFusion will return a WDDX packet; if you want JSON instead, add `&returnformat=json`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the WSDL to find out the methods exposed in the web service.

Comment: I did, I found couple of operations, but no luck access them through Visual Studio...